# Указание конструктора базового класса

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Когда необходимо явно указывать конструктор базового класса в конструкторе производного и когда его можно пропускать?

Приветствуется указание пунктов в стандарте языка.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/120876/2110496

Comment: Грубо - когда его можно опустить? Если у базового класса есть конструктор по умолчанию, и его вызов вас устраивает...